# Downloading tables in csv format using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, flask, beautifulsoup

I am building an application using Flask where if the user clicks on the button, all the html tables should be converted into CSV. I found one way to do this using Beautiful soup.

The issue is that Beautiful soup needs a url, since I am in the development phase I give it localhost: http://127.0.0.1:5000/results. However, all the tables are dynamic, which means that only when the  POST request for the endpoint upload_image() gets triggered, then the render template returns the html table (results.html) as the result. As you can see the entire function has the `@app.route('/results')`

The POST request with endpoint upload_image is:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
    file_names = []
    for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_names.append(filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            flash('File successfully uploaded')
            extracted_text = ocr_processing(file)
            print(extracted_text)
            match = extracted_text.lower()
            dark_pattern_file = "/Users/ri/Desktop/DPL/DP.csv"
            df = pd.read_csv(dark_pattern_file)
    for row in df.Pattern_String:
        result = ratio(row, match)
        print(result)
        if result >= 10:
            loaded_vec = CountVectorizer(
                vocabulary=pickle.load(open("model/tfidf_vector.pkl", "rb")))
            loaded_tfidf = pickle.load(open("model/tfidf_transformer.pkl", "rb"))
            model_pattern_type = pickle.load(
                open("model/clf_svm_Pattern_Category.pkl", "rb"))
            model_pattern_category = pickle.load(
                open("model/clf_svm_Pattern_Type.pkl", "rb"))
            match = [match]
            X_new_counts = loaded_vec.transform(
                match)
            # .values.astype('U')
            X_new_tfidf = loaded_tfidf.transform(X_new_counts)

            predicted_pattern_type = model_pattern_type.predict(X_new_tfidf)
            your_predicted_pattern_type = predicted_pattern_type[0]

            predicted_pattern_category = model_pattern_category.predict(
                X_new_tfidf)
            your_predicted_pattern_category = predicted_pattern_category[0]

            return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                                   msg='Processed successfully!',
                                   match=match,
                                   your_predicted_pattern_category=your_predicted_pattern_category,
                                   your_predicted_pattern_type=your_predicted_pattern_type,
                                   filenames=file_names,
                                   )
        else:
            return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                                   msg='Processed successfully!',
                                   match=match,
                                   filenames=file_names)
    else:
        flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
```

I have already created a download button and I wrote this function:

```
@app.route("/download", methods=['GET'])
def download_file():
    # with open("outputs/Adjacency.csv") as fp:
    #     csv = fp.read()
    # csv = '1,2,3\n4,5,6\n'
    html = urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:5000/results")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "results-table table-bordered table-hover"})
    print (table)
    rows = table.find("tr")

    with open("editors.csv", "wt+", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in rows:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"]):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

> As an error,         rows = table.find("tr")
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

It is unable to find any table and rows when I tried debugging. Like I mentioned the html table gets rendered only when the user uploads the image (see upload_image() endpoint)

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `urlopen()` to access your server. After opening, you need to read the contents using `.read()` in order to get the HTML.

So your script would need to be something like:

```
html = urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:5000/results").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

The error you are seeing is because the `table` variable is probably `None` signifying no table was found (in effect you were trying to do `None.find()`) Your print statement probably shows this too.

You should `print(html)` to verify you are seeing the expected HTML returned.

Comment: I get this error after making the suggested changes: http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Comment: That implies you have a problem with your server end. Try using a different URL e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/` to prove your script is ok.